# Filter Date from dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, filtering

This is the code in the controller:

```
// select only present date and distinct date for dropdownlist
var eventDate = from e in db.EVENTS
                .GroupBy(e =>new { e.EventDate})
                .Select(e => new { e.Key.EventDate})
                .OrderBy(e => e.EventDate)
                .Where(e => e.EventDate >= DateTime.Now)
                select e;

var ddlDate = from d in eventDate
              select d.EventDate;

ViewBag.EventDate = ddlDate;
```

This is markup in index.cshtml:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-2  col-lg-1 pb-1">
    <label class="col-form-label font-italic text-center">Filter :</label>
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-2 pb-1">
    @Html.DropDownList("searchCampus", new SelectList(ViewBag.Campus), "Select campus", new { @class = "form-control" }) <br />
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-2 pb-1">
@Html.DropDownList("searchDate", new SelectList(ViewBag.EventDate), "Select Event date", new { @class = "form-control" })
 </div>
```

[image: Date filter querystring mvc5]

I have an `EventDate` dropdownlist as a filter for my data. But I cannot compare my date in the query string to my `DateTime` datatype for `EventDate` column. I can see the date in the query string in my URL has `%` sign and other things mixing with my date.

How do I filter by date (dropdownlist is a list of `eventdate` I pull from `EventDate` column in database table), so when the user selects one of `EventDate` from dropdownlist, I want to show only the data that matches the `EventDate`.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi, your searchEventDate query string that has % sign in it can be converted into a readable string. Here is a reference for how to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8
Then you can convert the string into a DateTime for comparison.

Comment: Thank you Anthony! I am still looking for the the variable I should use HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string)